# file reading / reference issue in python

Tags: python, io

Recently I have referenced a file in my desktop using python 3.4 64bit GUI application. The problem I have got is as follows:

[image]

**The code I tried is :**

```
fo=open("c:\users\Ismail Nuru\Sesktop\myfile\lab.txt","r+")
string1=fo.read()
print(string1)
fo.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is trying to use the `\uXXXX` part of your string as a [unicode escape sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html).

To fix this, you have 3 options here:

1. Use a raw string `r'C:\users\Ismail Nuru\Sesktop\myfile\lab.txt'`
2. Double the backslashes `'C:\\users\\Ismail Nuru\\Sesktop\\myfile\\lab.txt'`
3. Or use forward slashes `'C:/users/Ismail Nuru/Sesktop/myfile/lab.txt')`